# Messed up Asus Chromebook Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, chromebook

My asus chromebook has a problem with it's keyboard. Everytime I press one of the following keys, w,s, and x,it comes out like this: wo,sl,and x.same happens but in reverse when i press o, l, or ., it comes out like ow, ls, and .x, now this started a few months ago. I don't remember but I might have spilled a small amount of milk on the keyboard from having milk and cookies one day, but i'm not sure. I have tried tunring it off and then back on but that hasn't worked, so i don't know what to do. I'm using my brother's computer to type this.

Answer (score 0):

Computers + Spillages don't work very well together.

You can try this YouTube video on "[How to Clean Up Keyboard Spills](https://youtu.be/fx2ZilgEmA0)".

[This lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5273016/how-to-save-your-keyboard-after-a-spill) is also pretty useful.

Another thing you can try is taking your keyboard apart and cleaning each key individually.